# Switch to Visual Studio from Full Screen debugged Application

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I debug some application which is always in full screen mode.

So when some error occurs I have to switch to Visual Studio. But I cannot or I hope I dont know how to do it correctly because if I use mouse / keys I cannot to do it by well known classic way but sometimes it happens.

My question is how to switch to Visual Studio from debugged application when it is stopped because of the debugged error when app in full screen mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of frustrating time spent constantly `Alt+Tab`-ing to the desktop, opening the task manager, and force-closing the running application. I say "constantly" because sometimes it doesn't work.

My advice: Have your Debug Configuration in windowed mode with the window at the correct resolution. Only run the Release Configuration in full screen. You should have any exceptional fatal error close the program. You notice this a lot in video games that "crash to desktop".