# How to stop fullscreen from locking PC when VS 2015 triggers a breakpoint?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, fullscreen, breakpoints, glfw

Booting my GLFW application in fullscreen is currently unsafe as if VS2015 decides to trigger a breakpoint due to some sort of error such as an access violation, I am completely locked into a black screen with a cursor on it until I forcibly reboot.

- The entire screen is black except for the mouse cursor, which is the spinning/waiting icon unless I move the cursor into the taskbar area.
- Locking does not fix it.
- Ctrl+Alt+Del does not fix it.
- I have to restart my PC with the power switch every time.

What can I do to make sure fullscreen debugging is *safe*, or dismiss the breakpoint message (that I probably cannot get to) while I'm "blind"?

Comment: The hotkey combinations (CTRL-ALT-<whatever>) to bring up VS tools differ in full-screen mode - why I don't know.    It's CTRL-ALT-X to get to the toolbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either:

1. Alt+Esc to switch the previous Window (supposedly VS)
2. Alt+Tab or Win+Tab to switch window and then pick the

VS window

then you can do something with the Exception handler/ breakpoint in VS

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is related to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11725773/switch-to-visual-studio-from-full-screen-debugged-application) i guess. So you should debug it in windowed mode and use the full screen mode only for the release.

Here is how to create a simple window with GLFW :

```
GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "My Title", NULL, NULL);
```